# multiselect filter array with nested object

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter, nested, multi-select

I use vue-multiselect to let user select items with filtering options:

```
query = "what user type in input field"
allLinks.filter(l=>l.labelName.includes(query))
```

and it works, but now I would like to extend the filtering to all properties of my object with this structure :

```
{
    "labelName":"LK000056",
    "extPort":{
        "aPort":"EXTA-EQ001/board10port02",
        "zPort":"EXTZ-EQ012/board09port02"
    }
}
```

I would like with one query to get parent object if query match on labelName, aPort or zPort.

it is possible ? or maybe with a conditional way like :

```
allLinks.filter(l=>if(!l.labelName.includes(query)){l.extport.aPort.includes(query)}else{l.extport.zPort.includes(query)})
```

thank for helping me

forgive my approximate English I am French

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could recursively flatten the objects to array of strings, then search in them via [**`Array.filter`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter), [**`Array.some`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) & [**`Array.includes`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes):

```js
const data = [{ "labelName":"LK000056", "extPort":{ "aPort":"EXTA-EQ001/board10port02", "zPort":"EXTZ-EQ012/board09port02" } }, { "labelName":"LK000057", "extPort":{ "aPort":"EXTA-EQ001/board123", "zPort":"EXTZ-EQ012/board333" } }]

const flatten = (obj, a=[]) => Object.values(obj)
  .reduce((r,c) => (typeof c == 'object' ? flatten(c,a) : r.push(c), r), a)

const search = (d, t) => 
  d.filter(x => flatten(x).some(x => x.toLowerCase().includes(t.toLowerCase())))

console.log(search(data, 'board123'))
console.log(search(data, 'LK000056'))
console.log(search(data, 'EXTZ-EQ012'))
```

Note that this is a **generic approach** and will work regardless of the nested levels of `data`, for example:

```js
const data = [{
  "A": {
    "B": {
      "C": {
        "data": '11'
      },
    }
  }
}, {
  "D": {
    "E": {
      "data": '22'
    }
  }
}, {
  "F": "33"
}]

const flatten = (obj, a = []) => Object.values(obj)
  .reduce((r, c) => (typeof c == 'object' ? flatten(c, a) : r.push(c), r), a)

const search = (d, t) => d.filter(x => 
  flatten(x).some(x => x.toLowerCase().includes(t.toLowerCase())))

console.log(search(data, '22'))
console.log(search(data, '11'))
console.log(search(data, '33'))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Object.values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values) to get the values of the object as an array, then use [some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) to test if one or more items match.

```js
const items = [{
  "labelName": "LK000056",
  "extPort": {
    "aPort": "EXTA-EQ001/board10port02",
    "zPort": "EXTZ-EQ012/board09port02"
  }
}, {
  "labelName": "234234",
  "extPort": {
    "aPort": "abc123",
    "zPort": "1234567890"
  }
}]

function search(query, data) {
  return data.filter(i => {
    if (i.labelName.includes(query)) return true
    if (Object.values(i.extPort).some(v => v.includes(query))) return true
    return false
  })
}

console.log(search("EQ001", items))
console.log(search("1234567890", items))
console.log(search("lalalala", items))
```

Answer (score 0):

if it can help I think found a functional solution let me know if something better can be done ...

```
allLinks.filter(l=>{
    if (l.sdhPort.zSDHPort!=undefined && l.extPort.aPort.toUpperCase().includes(query.toUpperCase())){return true}
    if (l.extport.zPort!=undefined && l.extPort.zPort.toUpperCase().includes(query.toUpperCase())){return true}
    if (l.labelName!=undefined && l.labelName.toUpperCase().includes(query.toUpperCase())){return true}
})
```

Answer (score 0):

wow thanks both of you !

it seems really interesting this technic ... but let me some time to understand it

what do think about what I found ?

best regards

Comment: You should delete this answer, as answers are only meant for answering questions. You should leave a comment to the answers instead.

Comment: Ok il will delete it and make answer for each reply. Thanks for the tip